# I cannot change Site Name position

Tags: theming

I am using the bluemarine theme Drupal 7, and I spent a lot of time trying uselessly to move down the site name. When I use the Firebug, it moves, but when I make changes on the style sheet it won't. I am using the following CSS lines:

```
#site-name {
  margin: 0.6em 0 0 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I tried with the above margin property and I even used margin-top property.
Even when I change the above font-size it won't change. Can you please save me from this vicious circle.
Thanks

Comment: your site name is either an id or a class (probably id), therefor you should use #site-name { ... } or .site-name { ... }

Comment: Yes it is a an ID as I missed to write it above. In the style sheet it should
#site-name {
margin 0.6em 0 0 0;
font-size: 2em;
}

Comment: Have you cleared the cache and disabled CSS aggregation? Otherwise the site might serve you a cached and compressed stylesheet

Comment: Yes I just cleared the cache and the CSS aggregation is not selected. I am also on a WAMP server.

Comment: try to set position property of your element. It may be an issue of margin collapse.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, I also noticed when I disable or enable a setting on the theme, like for example I disable shortcut icons, the changes on the style sheet works but if you change it on the sheet again it does not work.

Comment: I resolved the issue by reinstalling Drupal 7 and the CSS works normally now. Thanks a lot for the helps.